# get key of max value in dictionary when value is list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-analysis

```
myDict = {'DISPLAY': [0.12, 0.0], 'BATTERY': [0.5, 0.0]}
```

I want to check all values in each list and see the largest one. In this case, it is 0.5 which corresponds to the key "BATTERY" so I want to return "BATTERY". How can I do this? I would prefer not to iterate through everything again/make a new dict since I am already doing this in the previous steps of my code.

```
result = max(myDict, key=myDict.get)
```

wouldn't work properly in this case since the values are a list. For example, it doesn't work in this case when the largest value is not on the 0th index position of a list value.

```
{'DISPLAY': [0.16], 'BATTERY': [0.0, 0.77]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
max(myDict, key=lambda x: max(myDict[x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
max([x for l in myDict.values() for x in l])
```

The list comprehension "flattens" the list of lists (`myDict.values` returns a list of lists). `max` finds the highest value.